# be depleted of vs. deplete

Tags: usage

> We are depleting our resources.
> We are depleted of our resources.

Which is correct? If both of the sentences are correct, I guess there is a slight difference between the two sentences. The former focuses on the action while the latter the state. Is this right?

Comment: Please look up the verb to see whether it is transitive or not6.

Comment: The second version isn't very idiomatic - but more importantly *it means something different*. In the first version, ***we are causing our resources to become depleted***, but the second version is "agnostic" as to who is causing the depletion. And since the more common version explicitly says ***we*** are the cause, by the magic of Grice's Maxims we should assume that the second version intends to imply ***it's someone else's fault** [**we're** not the ones doing it].*

Answer (score 1):

Your assessment would be right if the two sentences were:

> We have depleted our resources.
> Our resources are depleted.

In this case, one focuses on the action, and the other on the state.

Let's look at the original examples:

> We are depleting our resources.

The difference here is that, by using the present continuous tense, it means that depletion is an ongoing process, and resources are not *all the way* depleted yet.

> We are depleted of our resources.

This one is just invalid, because "deplete" doesn't take a prepositional construction like that. "Deplete" can indeed be transitive ("we depleted our resources"), but you don't "deplete [someone] *of* [something]."

Comment: "Depleted of" is possible when there is a part-whole relation, e.g. the Google Books result "Too many of the foods we eat are depleted of nutrients".

Comment: @nschneid True. I would argue, though, that you still can't use that construction in active voice ("boiling depletes the food of its nutrients").

Comment: The active voice sounds fine to me. An attested example: "Cutting the green top off depletes it of vitamin K."

Comment: @nschneid You're right; [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deplete) gives the example "depleting the country of its natural resources." I'm not so sure now that anything is wrong with the given sentence; maybe it just sounds odd because of its extreme genericness...

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your example, the adjective '*depleted*' describes a resource that is almost (but not entirely) used up or reduced beyond a normal level. The verb '*depleting*' means to use up a resource in a way that could lead to it being depleted.

Your first example is grammatically correct, but make sure it means what you intend it to mean. Using something up isn't normally described as 'depleting' it unless there is some doubt over your ability to replenish it - for example, I wouldn't say "my car is depleting my fuel" just because it was burning it in the normal way. This verb means *using up*, not just using.

Your second example doesn't seem quite right - the adjective seems to be describing the state of people, not the supply. We might say "*we are short on resources*" to mean supplies are low, but 'depleted' tends to directly describe the resource, not the condition of people.